# Model returning error - ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 18) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm playing around with a keras based multi label classifer.  I created a function that loads training and test data and then I process/split X/Y within the function itself.  I'm getting a error when running my model but not quite sure the meaning:

Here's my code:

```
def KerasClassifer(df_train, df_test):
  X_train = df_train[columnType].copy()
  y_train = df_train[variableToPredict].copy()
  labels = y_train.unique()
  print(X_train.shape[1])
  #using keras to do classification
  from tensorflow import keras
  from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
  from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(5000, activation='relu', input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
  model.add(Dropout(0.1))
  model.add(Dense(600, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.1))
  model.add(Dense(len(labels), activation='sigmoid'))

  sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=sgd)

  model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=2000)

  preds = model.predict(X_test)
  preds[preds>=0.5] = 1
  preds[preds<0.5] = 0

  score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=2000)
  score
```

Here are attributes of my data(if it helps):

```
x train shape  (392436, 109)
y train shape  (392436,)
len of y labels 18
```

How can I fix the code to avoid this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 18 categories the shape of `y_train` should be `(392436, 18)`. You can use `tf.one_hot` for that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train, depth=len(labels))
```

And if you're taking your values from one column, I suspect this is not "multi-label", but multi-class. Can a sample really belong to multiple categories? If not, you will need to change a few other things too. For instance, you would need softmax activation:

```
model.add(Dense(len(labels), activation='softmax'))
```

And also categorical crossentropy loss:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
```

Answer (score 4):

your labels are 1D... you need to one-hot encode them if your aim is to operate a **multi label task**. You can simple use

`tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes)`

in this way you transform your target from (n_sample) to (n_sample, num_classes)

if it's a simple **multi class** problem instead you have these 2 possibilities:

**1 possibility)** if you have 1D integer encoded target, you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function with `softmax` activation to generate probabilities

```
n_class = 3
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)

pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X), 1)
```

**2 possibility)** if you have one-hot encoded your target in order to have 2D shape `(n_samples, num_classes)`, you can use `categorical_crossentropy` with `softmax` activation to generate probabilities

```
n_class = 3
n_features = 100
n_sample = 1000

X = np.random.randint(0,10, (n_sample,n_features))
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample))

inp = Input((n_features,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)

pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X), 1)
```