# What is best practice for categorical encoding (one-hot-encoding) of labels for deep learning (keras)?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have about 8000 unique labels in my trainingset, and maybe half of those labels in my test set (I'm building a rec system). I can do various form of one-hot encodings. Easiest one being pd.get_dummies() since I have my data in pandas df.

But what is the best practice to encode my df_train['labels'], and get the same encoding on my df_train['labels']?

Right now, I am concatenating df_train and df_test, then do the pd.get_dummies(), and then splitting the merged df again. But I'm thinking it has to be a better way? Like fit on the training data, then transform on train and test?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690765/10375049

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't solve my problem. You need the categories to be encoded exactly the same in both the test, and train set. If you encode them separately like the posts in the link suggest, you may end up with different encodings. In my case, having different numbers of classes in the different sets, you will definitely end up with different classes.

Comment: use LabelEncoding (from sklearn) to integer map your train and transform your test/unseen data... in this way, the categories are encoded exactly the same in both the test, and train set

Comment: I've been looking at the OneHotEncoder from sklearn which should do what I want to do. Thanks for the inputs :)